Debug Godot C# in Mixed Mode to Diagnose UI Problem
I try to debug a non-game application in Godot as I use Godot as an UI-toolkit for its fast compile and build times and the control it provides.
I upgraded it recently from 4.0.x to 4.2.1 and now experienced a lot of errors regarding calling certain methods on nodes outside of Godot's main thread as they changed the behavior to prepare for multi-threaded access to the node tree.
Since this error is raised by the core part of Godot being written in C++ I need mixed mode debugging capabilities to easily diagnose the reason for this error by getting the information about the call stack.
I want to get the outcome similar to what another user provided me as the example how he sees the error in his debugging session:

E 0:00:01:0065   Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.generated.cs:345 @ void Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.godotsharp_method_bind_ptrcall(IntPtr , IntPtr , System.Void** , System.Void* ): This function in this node (/root/Control/Panel/MarginContainer2/HBoxContainer/Label2) can only be accessed from either the main thread or a thread group. Use call_deferred() instead.
<C++ Error>    Condition "!is_readable_from_caller_thread()" is true.
Returning: (false)
<C++ Source>   scene/gui/control.cpp:3047 @ is_auto_translating()
  Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.generated.cs:345 @ void Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.godotsharp_method_bind_ptrcall(IntPtr , IntPtr , System.Void** , System.Void* )
NativeCalls.cs:434 @ void Godot.NativeCalls.godot_icall_1_49(IntPtr , IntPtr , System.String )
Label.cs:357 @ void Godot.Label.SetText(System.String )
Label.cs:27 @ void Godot.Label.set_Text(System.String )
Launch.cs:125 @ void Launch.UpdateVersionLabel()
Launch.cs:80 @ void Launch.<_Ready>b__10_0(System.Object )
Update.cs:39 @ void PatchLibrary.Updater.set_State(PatchLibrary.EState )
Update.cs:236 @ void PatchLibrary.Updater
d__68.MoveNext():0 @ void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start (TStateMachine& ):0 @ System.Threading.Tasks.Task PatchLibrary.Updater.InternalUpdate()
Update.cs:199 @ void PatchLibrary.Updater+<b__63_0>d.MoveNext():0 @ void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<TStateMachine
(TStateMachine& ):0 @ System.Threading.Tasks.Task PatchLibrary.Updater
b__63_0():0 @ void System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()

I therefore installed Visual Studio 22 Community Edition, installed the Godot extension from Github and created a launch profile for an executable running Godot's 4.2.1 '_console' executable while also checking the Mixed Debugging (Native Debugging) mode option.
When running it in a debug session, it runs the application but it does not suspend the flow when the error is raised in the C++ code section causing it.
I still wonder if I need a special build of the Godot engine for debug symbols and I also wonder how do I have to configure the VC debugger to suspend the application on the given error as I had my fair share of experience with VC and Godot 4 years ago but I do not remember mucha and guess I simply overlook something simple and basic here in order to get the desired outcome.
Many thanks!
